# How to stub return value for the private method of same class using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am working on spring based project and writing unit test case using JUnit + Mockito. I am facing a problem while stubbing boolean value to a private method of same test class (after changing access level to public, still I have failed to stub the boolean value).

Below code snippet shows the simulation of same problem

```java
class ABC {

    public String method1(User userObj){
        String result = "";

        if(!isValidUser(userObj.getSessionID())){
            return "InvalidUser";
        } else {
           // execute some logic
        }

        return result;
    }


    private boolean isValidUser(String sessionId) {
        // Here it calls some other class to validate the user 
        if (sessionId == null || UserSessionPool.getInstance().getSessionUser(sessionId) == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Here, I would like to write a test case for method1(). In class ABC I have a method called `isValidUser()` which helps to identify the user with in a session by looking into a global session pool which holds all logged-in used details i.e. `UserSessionPool.getInstance().getSessionUser(sessionId)`.

While testing method1(), the moment test controller triggers `isValidUser(userObj.getSessionID())` I would like to return `true` from `isValidUser()` method, so that I can continue to test rest of the implementation logic.

So far I have tried following ways using spy and mocked object to call the `isValidUser()` method and try to return true but nothing worked well.

**Using PowerMockito**

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(spyed_ABC_ClassObject, "isValidUser", true);
```

or

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(cntrl, "isValidUser", Mockito.anyString());
```

**Using Whitebox**

```
Whitebox.invokeMethod(spyed_ABC_ClassObject, "isValidUser", Mockito.anyString());
```

**Using Mockito.when**

```
when(spyed_ABC_ClassObject.isValidUser(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(true);
```

or

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(spyed_ABC_ClassObject).isValidUser(Mockito.anyString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this out.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    UserSessionPool mockConnectionPool = Mockito.mock(UserSessionPool.class);
}

@Test
public void testName() throws Exception {
    //given
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(UserSessionPool.class);
    BDDMockito.given(UserSessionPool.getInstance()(...)).willReturn(mockConnectionPool);
    Mockito.when(mockConnectionPool.getSessionUser(Mockito.anylong())).thenReturn(something);


    //then
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic();

}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: Ravindra Ranwala thanks for your answer, but it is giving exception while executing `BDDMockito.given(UserSessionPool.getInstance()(...)).willReturn(mockConnectionPool);` like `MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.`

Comment: Can you please tell me what is `(...)` on BDDMockito method

Comment: I have commented `BDDMockito.given(UserSessionPool.getInstance()).willReturn(mockConnectionPool)` this line of code with some simple code alteration I was able to do this. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is: fix your *design* instead of turning to the big PowerMock hammer.

Yes, PowerMock allows you to *mock* static methods. But you should understand: *static* is an **abnormality** in good OO design. You only use it when you have very good reasons. As it leads to **tight** coupling between your classes, and surprise: it **breaks** your ability to write reasonable unit tests. Yes, PowerMock works; but sometimes, it does not. When your classes grow, and you do more and more things "statically", because, you know, PowerMock will do the job ... be prepared for bizarre fails at some point, that can take hours to hunt down; without ever finding real bugs in your production code.

So, consider an alternative:

1. Do not use static method calls. And if there is some static method around that you can't touch; consider building a small interface around that.
2. Instead: use dependency injection and simply pass objects implementing some interface into your production code. Because you can mock such objects **without** the need for PowerMock(ito).

In that sense: you simply created **hard to test** code. Now you intend to fix that using PowerMock. The other way (much more reasonable in my eyes) is to learn how to write **testable** code in the first place. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) is a good starting point for that.